# Spotify cacheing songs on shared network drive

Tags: spotify

I know you can change the location where spotify stores its cached songs, but i was wondering if you could move it to a network drive, and have multiple PC's access it, this way we reduce the amount of downloads within our company

has anyone tried this?

Comment: (1) Is this question for Windows? (2) What happens if in Preferences / Local Files you use "Add Source" to add a network location?

Comment: 1. windows pc's only, 2. not sure, we have not set it up yet

Comment: Try (2). If it works then problem is solved, if not then we need other ideas.

Comment: I was hoping someone has already tried, so that i wouldn't have to invest money into unnecessary hardware. but worse case this is the path i will take. thanks @harrymc

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure this is a good idea, since the cache is used for fast access.
A network drive is slower to access than normal media.
Of course how slow/fast depends on what device it is and what interface it uses to connect to the network (USB/ethernet  etc...)

On top of that I am not sure if this will be a good idea from an amount of concurrent users perspective.

Maybe you should block Spotify and tell people to use their phones' mobile network data plans or local music files?

Edit: To actually answer you question instead of questioning it, Spotify supports caching on network drives I just found out. I haven't tried it, but it should be possible.

Maybe you should try with a simple thumb drive or HDD and see if it works optimally?